# I have simple design and need to put it on magento

Tags: magento

I have design (css, some html files and images) and I need to adapt it to magento.
I know how to change design templates, but is this possible to do it with my own design and how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid being overly long in reply, here's the pretty definitive resource on applying your design to Magento:

[The Magento Designer's Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide)